# 'int' object is not iterable -- openCV python raspberry

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Project/mainf.py", line 145, in <module>
    predicted_img1 = predict(test_img1)
  File "/home/pi/Project/mainf.py", line 83, in predict
    label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(face)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

My tasks is when it runs it takes some photographs using webcam and saves the file by current date and time .jpg . when system try to read the file for facial recognition it throws error. My directory is one named test-data where the file has been saved. and another one is training-data have subfolder named s1 and s2 which contains image of a person

```
import cv2
import sys
import time
import os
import glob
import operator
import numpy as np


subjects = ["", "Sanjeev", "Vijay"]


cascPath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

#function to detect face using OpenCV
def detect_face(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('opencv-files/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml')
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5);
    if (len(faces) == 0):
        return None, None    
    (x, y, w, h) = faces[0]
    return gray[y:y+w, x:x+h], faces[0]


#function to prepare a training set.
def prepare_training_data(data_folder_path):
    dirs = os.listdir(data_folder_path)
    faces = []
    labels = []
    for dir_name in dirs:
        if not dir_name.startswith("s"):
            continue;
        label = int(dir_name.replace("s", ""))
        subject_dir_path = data_folder_path + "/" + dir_name
        subject_images_names = os.listdir(subject_dir_path)
        for image_name in subject_images_names:
            if image_name.startswith("."):
                continue;
            image_path = subject_dir_path + "/" + image_name
            image = cv2.imread(image_path)
            face, rect = detect_face(image)
            if face is not None:
                faces.append(face)
                labels.append(label)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return faces, labels

faces, labels = prepare_training_data("training-data")


#create our LBPH face recognizer 
#face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
face_recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

#face_recognizer = cv2.face.EigenFaceRecognizer_create()

#face_recognizer = cv2.face.FisherFaceRecognizer_create()


#train our face recognizer of our training faces
face_recognizer.train(faces, np.array(labels))


def draw_rectangle(img, rect):
    (x, y, w, h) = rect
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

def draw_text(img, text, x, y):
    cv2.putText(img, text, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)


def predict(test_img):
    img = test_img.copy()
    face, rect = detect_face(img)

    label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(face)
    print(confidence)
    print(label)
    label_text = subjects[label]
    draw_rectangle(img, rect)
    draw_text(img, label_text, rect[0], rect[1]-5)
    if confidence <=20:                     
        print(subjects[label]+"is a known face")
        return img                          
    else:
        print("Unknown face found")


video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    if ret is True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    else:
        continue

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        #flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    #Save just the rectangle faces in SubRecFaces
        sub_face = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
        FaceFileName = "test-data/"+timestr+str(y)+ ".jpg"
        #FaceFileName = "test-data/"+"san"+ ".jpg"
        cv2.imwrite(FaceFileName, sub_face)


    # Display the resulting frame
    #cv2.imshow('Video', frame)


    #getting latest file names
    list_of_files = glob.glob('test-data/*.*') # * means all if need specific format then *.csv
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    #index=latest_file.rfind('\\')
    #new_file = latest_file[index+1:]
    #print('test-data/'+new_file)
    #print new_file
    #print latest_file

    #load test images
    test_img1 = cv2.imread(latest_file)
    #test_img1 = cv2.imread("test-data/test1.jpg")
    #test_img2 = cv2.imread('test-data/'+new_file)

    #perform a prediction
    predicted_img1 = predict(test_img1)
    #predicted_img1 = predict(test_img1)
    #predicted_img2 = predict(test_img2)

    time.sleep(2.0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: `face_recognizer.predict` returns an `int`. Thus, your unpacking assignment with two variable names on the left is doomed to fail.

Comment: how do i fix that ?

Comment: Don't try to unpack the result.

Comment: sorry, but i am new to python,  can you explain

Comment: If you are having troubles with the words "unpacking", "integer" or "assignment" you should go back to a tutorial and not jump into opencv.

Comment: He means that that line should be like `label = face_recognizer.predict(face)` . If you read the docs it tells you that it returns the label. And I agree with @timgeb, you should try some python tutorials first, or you will have a bad time with OpenCV